# How to calculate elevation of the point?

Tags: gps, geometry, elevation

I have two points: A ( x1 ( latitude ), y1 ( longitude ), z1 ( elevation ) ) and B ( x2, y2, z2 ). x1,y1,z1 and x2,y2 are known, also I know the distance between A and B.

How can I calculate z2 without using internet, totally offline ? ( I am using Google Maps on Android )

Comment: Do you have an offline DEM to obtain the data from? Do you have a 3d vector from A to B? Distance is not enough to calculate Z for x2,y2.

Comment: You see I have only my coordinates ( x1, y1 ) from GPS, z1 from Android sensors and x2,y2 and AB from Google Maps. Nothing more :( Actually Ieven do not know what is DEM.

Comment: A DEM is a Digial Elevation Model, a floating point (usually) raster of elevations.. depending on how accurate you want there are free elevation models available - see SRTM http://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/ you work out your row, column from your x2,y2 and then read that cell for your elevation.

Comment: Got it. But how I guess DEM is a map, right ? So have to use or Google Map or DEM ?